# Testing CSRF protecting views in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was hitting a wall when it comes to testing my APIViews that require authentication. I wanted to test that both CSRF and authentications + permissions were enforced as expected.

Some information of my setup:

- My view is a Django Rest Framework `rest_framework.views.APIView` which implements the `post` function.
- Default authentication classes are `SessionAuthentication`
- Default permission classes are `IsAuthenticated`
- Test cases use the `APIClient` to issue requests

When initializing the `APIClient` with `enforce_csrf_checks=True` I still can't seem to get the response I'm expecting when it comes to views that require authentication (using the `IsAuthenticated` permission class).

For non-authenticated views, I can test CSRF protection, no problem.

The view in question:

```
@method_decorator(csrf_protect)
def post(self, request, format=None):
    """
    Create a new user.
    """
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The test code:

```
client = APIClient()
response = client.post(url, data)
# Success!

client = APIClient(enforce_csrf_checks=True)
response = client.post(url, data)
# 403 FORBIDDEN
```

For authenticated views, things get weird (this view uses the `IsAuthenticated` permission:

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
    """
    Get request user.
    """
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    serializer = UserSerializer(user)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The test code:

```
self.client = APIClient(enforce_csrf_checks=True)
self.client.login(email='t@t.se', password='pw')

self.client.get(url)
# Succeeds, even though it should not. No CSRF HTTP header is set.
```

It seems the client initialization parameter `enforce_csrf_checks` does not do anything or I have not understood how it should be used.

Comment: I'm not 100% comfortable with how CSRF tokens work but aren't they supposed to protect POST, PUT and DELETE requests? I don't think GET requests ever require CSRF validations (django's docs don't seem to mention this at least): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/. How does this test behave for POST requests?

Comment: Very good point, this is most likely the problem. Why I want to protect this view in particular is to try and make sure no session hijacker can access sensitive user data and personal information. But, I don't know enough about CSRF to understand why GET requests are not considered CSRF protection "worthy". I did some tests to prove your comment and I have no issues whatsoever with CSRF protecting POST views, only GET.

Comment: It seems that CSRF protection is destined to prevent modifying data on your server, which GET requests don't do (aren't supposed to at least). Wild guess but maybe there's something that could be done with the request.META info (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) to check where the request comes from (your site or a malicious site...?). Not sure you'd get any HTTP_REFERER data but it's worth a shot?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm trying to use a screwdriver to hammer in a nail. I will have to find some other way of protecting the GET views from malicious intent. Thanks a bunch for your comments, I'll write your input as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Clepsyd in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64298998/testing-csrf-protecting-views-in-django-rest-framework?noredirect=1#comment113707603_64298998), CSRF is not meant to protect GET method views from requests originating from a hijacked session. Turns out, I only really have "problems" CSRF protecting GET views and nothing else. As it is not intended to use CSRF protection on GET views, my question was irrelevant and I will need to find another way of protecting my GET views to prevent data leakage.